# SQLite3, creating a relation one to many

Tags: sqlite

I'm creating an sqlite3 database with two tables. This is how I want it to be:

```
create table user(
    id NOT NULL,
    name varchar(40),
    password varchar(40)
)

create table users_data(
    id NOT NULL
    note_name varchar(40),
    note_description varchar(255),
)
```

and I want it to use one to many relation, so that one user has many note_name and note_description. How do I do this using SQlite?

Answer (score 0):

You add the user id to the table users_data, because every users_data belongs to a user. That's it. Then let the database system help you guarantee data integrity with primary and foreign keys:

```
create table user(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(40),
    password varchar(40)
);

create table users_data(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    id_user integer NOT NULL,
    note_name varchar(40),
    note_description varchar(255),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_user) REFERENCES user(id)
);
```

Read more on foreign keys here: https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html